# how to publish in azure an asp.net mvc4 solution n layers

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4, azure-web-app-service

I have a project with mvc 4 simple in azure, now it adds layers so when updating does not work, how do I publish or attach the layers I've added?

Comment: English only on this site please, including the title. Are you looking for https://pt.stackoverflow.com/ ? or https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not in English - this is an **English-only** site - please respect the rules of the site!

Comment: hola amigo, ingles por favor ;)

Answer (score 0):

> how to publish in azure an asp.net mvc4 solution n layers

If you implement your layer using class library, please make sure the DLL is referenced by your web application and copied to your Azure web app.

[image]

If you implement your layer using Web API or Web Service, you need to deploy your layers to the separate Azure Web App.

Comment: Any update? If you have further questions, please feel free to let me know.